# How to create multiple configuration on WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, mvvm

I have a WPF project that connects to a Business Logic Project Class Library and Business Logic connects to a Web Service. Since the Web Service has a local, UAT and Production version. I would like to create a App.Debug.config, App.UAT.config, App.Release.config under a App.config. I am trying to do the same thing from my previous Web Application but I don't know why it doesn't work. I was able to create the 3 configs but the value doesn't change when debugging. I used the XML-Document-Transform but doesn't work. Here is what I tried:

.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectConfigFileName>App.config</ProjectConfigFileName>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="App.config" />
   <None Include="App.Debug.config">
     <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
   </None>
   <None Include="App.UAT.config">
     <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
   </None>
   <None Include="App.Release.config">
     <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WCFURL" value="test.com/default.svc" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

App.Debug.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WCFURL" value="test.com/debug.svc" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

App.UAT.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WCFURL" value="test.com/uat.svc" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

App.Release.config

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WCFURL" value="test.com/release.svc" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Even if I run it on any config setting I still end up getting the default value from App.config.

Comment: Xml transformation only works automatically for web apps. You need an add-in for it to work on others.  Take a look at slowcheetah.https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/

Comment: So there is no solution for this that doesn't require Nuget. Any solution other than using config is fine for me as long as it is similar and solves the problem. Thanks